# Ionic 3 LocalStorage sumindo

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic3, localstorage

Tenho uma aplicação em Ionic 1 que salva algumas informações no localStorage.
Reescrevi a mesma aplicação em Ionic 3 com o mesmo package id(widget id no config.xml), mas ao instalar a aplicação nova por cima da antiga eu perco o localStorage, ele vem vazio.

Se eu instalar novamente a antiga por cima da nova eu consigo enxergar novamente o localStorage, é como se fossem aplicações diferentes, mas estão com o mesmo package id e eu sempre instalo uma por cima da outra.

Isso acontece apenas no celular, as aplicações não estão compartilhando o mesmo localStorage. Ao acessar o Devtools do google na aba "Application" - "Storage" - "Local Storage" aparece "file://" quando rodo a aplicação criada em Ionic 1 e aparece "http://localhost:8080" quando rodo a aplicação criada em Ionic 3.

Tem alguma particularidade no Ionic 3 que não consegue enxergar/acessar o localStorage do Ionic 1 e vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

A localStorage não é um local seguro para guardar dados. Os dados periodicamente podem ser apagados pelo sistema operativo. A melhor solução é usar o "Native Storage": https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/